# Strange behavior with touchDragged

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a problem with a simple thing - I'm trying to impement dragging for actor, but I see strange effect - when I try to drag actor it starts blinking and change positions randomly. Here is a short video: https://youtu.be/KpGujQ7KHc0

Actor is simple:

```
public class Item extends Actor {
    private String id;
    private TextureRegion texture;

    public Item() {
        this.id = "passport";

        texture = PicturesData.getPicture(getId());
        setSize(texture.getRegionWidth(), texture.getRegionHeight());

        addListener(new DragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                Log.add("Dragged: " + x + ", " + y);
                setPosition(x, y);
            }
        });
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY());
    }
}
```

The screen is basic too:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    private Stage stage;

    public GameScreen() {
        stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(800, 600));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        Item item = new Item();

        stage.addActor(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

I have no idea why it's happening, could you please help me?

Comment: Is there anywhere else in your code where the position of this Actor is changed?

Comment: No. I updated my post with Screen code. It is pretty basic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasha, there's nothing wrong with your DragListener. Use this Item (starting position hardcoded):

```
public class Item extends Image {
    private String id;

    public Item(String id) {
        super(PicturesData.getPicture(getId());
        this.id = id;
        setPosition(50, 50);
        addListener(new DragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                moveBy(x - getWidth()/2, y - getHeight()/2);
            }
        });
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: The same bug for me. What libgdx version do you use? Is it ok for you? Mine is 1.9.3, but I also tried with 1.9.1... Maybe I should report it in libgdx's github...

Comment: Yes, it works! They should write in javadoc that `X` and `Y` in `touchDragged` are not new position, but delta with previous position! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your `DragListener` isn't working correctly is because you have overridden the `touchDown` function which is required for the listener to function correctly. Just change your code to this:

```
addListener(new DragListener() {
        @Override
        public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            Log.add("Dragged: " + x + ", " + y);
            setPosition(x, y);
        }
    });
```

Comment: As I know, this is correct to override `touchDown`. From javadoc for `touchDragged`: _Called when a mouse button or a finger touch is moved anywhere, but **only if touchDown previously returned true** for the mouse button or touch_. Anyway, I tried to remove `touchDown` -- result is still the same :(